# DDD Value Object: How to persist entity objects without tons of SQL joins?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, domain-driven-design, object-persistence

Obviously I am wrong in saying that DDD is similar to EAV/CR in usefulness, but the only difference I see so far is physical tables build for each entity with lots of joins rather than three tables and lots of joins.

This must be due to my lack of DDD understanding.  **How do you physically store these objects to the database without significant joins and complication when importing data?**  I know you can simply create objects that feed in to your repository, but it's difficult to train tools like Microsoft Sql Server Integration Server to use your custom C# objects and framework.  Maybe that should be my question, how do you use your DDD ASP.NET C# framework with Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services and Report Services? LOL.

In an EAV/CR database, we can setup a single Person table with different classes depending on the type of person: Vendor, Customer, Buyer, Representative, Company, Janitor, etc.  Three tables, a few joins, attributes are always string with validation before we insert, just like ModelValidation in MVC where the object accepts any value but won't persist until it's valid.

In a standard relational model, we used to create a table for each type of entity, mixing in redundant data types like City.

Using Domain Driven Design, we use objects to represent each type of entity, nested objects for each type of ValueObject, and more nested objects still as necessary.  In my understanding, this results in a table for each kind of entity and a table for each kind of information set (value object).  With all these tables, I see a lot of joins.  We also end up creating a physical table for each new contact type.  Obviously there is a better way, so I must be incorrect in how I persist objects to a database.

My Vendor looks like this:

```
public class Vendor {
    public int vendorID {get; set;}
    public Address vAddress {get; set;}
    public Representative vRep {get;set;}
    public Buyer vBuyer {get; set;}
}
```

My Buyer:

```
public class Buyer {
   public int buyerID {get; set;}
   public Address bAddress {get; set;}
   public Email bEmail {get; set;}
   public Phone bPhone {get; set;}
   public Phone bFax (get; set;}
}
```

Do we really reference things like Vendor.vBuyer.bPhone.pAreaCode?  I would think we would reference and store Vendor.BuyerPhoneNumber, and build the objects almost like aliases to these parts: Vendor.Address1, Vendor.Address2, Vendor.BuyerPhoneNumber ... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer is to match your SQL normalization strategy to your objects.  If you have lots of duplicate addresses and you need to associate them together, then normalize the data to a separate table, thus creating the need for the value object.

Answer (score 1):

You could serialize your objects to xml and save it to an xml column in you Sql Server. After all, you are trying to represent a hierarchical data structure, and that's where xml excels.

Answer (score 1):

Domain-driven design proponents often recommend keeping the data model as close to the object model as possible, but it isn't an ironclad rule.

You can still use [a EAV/CR database design](http://ycmi.med.yale.edu/nadkarni/eav_CR_contents.htm) if you create mappings in your object-relational mapping layer to transform (project) your data into your objects.

Deciding how to design your objects and provide access to child values is really a separate question that you have to address on a case-by-case basis. `Vendor.BuyerPhoneNumber` or `Vendor.vBuyer.bPhone.pAreaCode`? The answer always depends, because it's rooted in your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to store Domain Objects is actually a document database. It works beautifully because the transactional boundary of the document matches perfectly the consistency boundary of the Aggregate Root. You don't have to worry about JOINs, or eager/lazy loading issues. That's not strictly necessary, though, if you apply CQRS (which I've written about below).

The downside is often with querying. If you wish to query directly the persisted data behind your Domain Objects, you can get into knots. However that is a complexity that CQRS aims to solve for you, where you have different parts of your application doing the queries than the parts loading/validating/storing Domain Objects.

You might have a complex "Command" implementation that loads Domain Objects, invokes the behaviour on them (remembering that Domain Objects must have behaviour and encapsulate their data, or else risk becoming "anaemic"), before saving them and optionally even publishing events about what happened.

You might then use those events to update some other "read store", though you don't have to. The point is you have a totally different vertical slice implemented in your application that doesn't have to bother with that complex object model/ORM business, and instead goes straight to the data, loads exactly what it needs and returns it for displaying to the user.

CQRS is *not* hard, and is *not* complex. *All* it does is instruct you to have separate code for:

1. Handling commands (which mutate state and therefore need the business rules/invariants involved).
2. Executing queries (which do not mutate state and therefore don't need all the complex business rules/invariants involved, and so can "just" go get the data in an efficient way.